# Play 2 framework Internationalization not working in if statement

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, scala-template

I am working with Play 2.3.8.

In my views, some of my internationalized messages are not displayed.

I suspect a bug in play? The code `@play.i18n.Messages.get("calendar.level.0.criterias.title")` works perfectly OUTSIDE of the if statement, but not inside. What is happening? Can I not use scala variables within some scala code?

here is my code:

```
@if (user == null) {
  <p style="padding-bottom: 0px;">@play.i18n.Messages.get("calendar.level.0.criterias.title")</p>
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is a problem with the message and not with `@if (user == null)`?

Comment: Is there an error or does it just not appear? Can you have a look at the source in the browser and check whether `<p style="padding-bottom: 0px;">` is displayed? if the p-tag does not show up, then @Tom is probably right and the problem lies with the if-clause.